# Fisheye lens stereo calibration OpenCV, Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, fisheye

I'm trying to create disparity map with see3cam 40 camera which is  RAW RGB-IR USB3 camera with fisheye lens of 131 degrees. I've  successfully calibrated my camera using this tutorial  [link](https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-333b05afa0b0) as reference. This is the code:

```
CHESSBOARD_SIZE = (9,6)
img_dir_left = "/home/dir_left"
img_dir_right = "/home/dir_right"


criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS+cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.1)
calib_flags = cv2.fisheye.CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC+cv2.fisheye.CALIB_CHECK_COND+cv2.fisheye.CALIB_FIX_SKEW

objp = np.zeros((1, CHESSBOARD_SIZE[0]*CHESSBOARD_SIZE[1], 3), np.float32)
objp[0,:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:CHESSBOARD_SIZE[0], 0:CHESSBOARD_SIZE[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)

def calculate(imgDir):
    imgPath = glob.glob(imgDir+'/*jpg')
    img_size = None 
    objpoints = []
    imgpoints = [] 

    for image in sorted(imgPath):
        img = cv2.imread(image)
        if img_size == None:
            img_size = img.shape[:2]
        else:
            assert img_size == img.shape[:2], "All images must share the same size."

         gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
         ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, CHESSBOARD_SIZE, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK+cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)

        if ret:
            objpoints.append(objp)
            cornersM = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
            imgpoints.append(cornersM)

        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, CHESSBOARD_SIZE, cornersM, ret)
        cv2.imshow(imgDir, img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    return objpoints, imgpoints, img_size, gray

def calibrate(objpoints, imgpoints, img_size, gray):
    img_number = len(objpoints) #number of the pictures
    K = np.zeros((3, 3))
    D = np.zeros((4, 1))
    rvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64) for i in range(img_number)]
    tvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64) for i in range(img_number)]

    print("rvecs", rvecs)

    rms, _, _, _, _ = cv2.fisheye.calibrate(objpoints,imgpoints,gray.shape[::-1],K,D,rvecs,tvecs,calib_flags,
     (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS+cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 1e-6))

    print("RMS", rms)
    print("Found " + str(img_number) + " valid images for calibration")
    print("DIM=" + str(img_size[::-1]))
    print("K=np.array(" + str(K.tolist()) + ")", )
    print("D=np.array(" + str(D.tolist()) + ")\n", )

    dimension = img_size[::-1]
    k = K.tolist()
    d = D.tolist()

    return  dimension , k , d
```

I've taken 13 images peer camera at the same time. Images are transformed from raw 10 bit state to 8 bit. Cameras are mounted in the same line with 7 cm baseline. My RMS_left is 0.509 and RMS_right 0.341.

This is function I use to undistort frames from the camera.

```
def undistorted(frame, data):
    data_in = data
    img = frame
    K, D, DIM = data_in['K'], data_in['D'], data_in['DIM']
    K = np.array(K)
    D = np.array(D)

    map1, map2 = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, np.eye(3), K, DIM, cv2.CV_16SC2)#cv2.CV_16SC2   
    undistorted_frame = cv2.remap(img, map1, map2,   interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_TRANSPARENT,  borderValue=29)

   return undistorted_frame
```

When I try to do fisheye stereo calibration I get the same errors described in this github [link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11085). But there is a workaround for all the errors.

```
K_left = np.zeros((3, 3))
D_left = np.zeros((4, 1))

K_right = np.zeros((3, 3))
D_right = np.zeros((4, 1))

R = np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64)
T = np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64)

N_OK = len(imgpoints_left)

objp = np.zeros( (CHECKERBOARD[0]*CHECKERBOARD[1], 1, 3) , np.float64)
objp[:,0, :2] = np.mgrid[0:CHECKERBOARD[0], 0:CHECKERBOARD[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)

objpoints = np.array([objp]*len(imgpoints_left),dtype=np.float64)
imgpoints_left = np.asarray(imgpoints_left, dtype=np.float64)
imgpoints_right = np.asarray(imgpoints_right, dtype=np.float64)

objpoints = np.reshape(objpoints, (N_OK, 1, CHECKERBOARD[0]*CHECKERBOARD[1], 3))
imgpoints_left = np.reshape(imgpoints_left, (N_OK, 1, CHECKERBOARD[0]*CHECKERBOARD[1], 2))
imgpoints_right = np.reshape(imgpoints_right, (N_OK, 1, CHECKERBOARD[0]*CHECKERBOARD[1], 2))    

(rms, K_left, D_left, K_right, D_right, R, T) = \
    cv2.fisheye.stereoCalibrate(
        objpoints,
        imgpoints_left,
        imgpoints_right,
        K_left,
        D_left,
        K_right,
        D_right,
        img_size,
        R,
        T,
        calibration_flags
    )
```

Can someone help me to clarify this workaround, I'm new to OpenCV to understand it completely.

Comment: What did you want in np.reshape part? I didn't use it and wondered why it is doing for code part. Other than I didn't see any errors so far. We can solve it somehow

Comment: Thanks for answering! I found that there was issue with OpenCV libs .I've solved the issue by doing calibration and stereo rectification using Matlab, then importing the results in Python and doing stereo calculation and filtering via OpenCV 3.4 . with this approach I was able to solve it.

Comment: I thank you for answering the question. Very nice of you. Matlab calibration tools are very powerful and I believe it is simpler than opencv. Especially in case of fisheye, you can't estimate in which degree we should use wide angle lens calibration or fisheye. I wish you very good day!